# Only arabic text changing size, not the other text on string

Tags: java, android

i tried using sharedpreferences to save the values. and i use seekbar to change the value of font size. sharedpreferences works well and also for the font size changing as i want. however, only arabic text been changing, but not the translation. the text i call from string resources.

here is the code.

```
public class fontsize extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


    //textsize

    int textSize = 30;

    //textView


    TextView textViewFont, textViewSize;

    //SharedPreferences

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;




    //variablesmenudrawer

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fontsize);



        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("fontsize", MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        int progress = sharedPreferences.getInt("progress", 0);


        //definingtextview

        textViewFont = findViewById(R.id.textViewFont);
        textViewSize = findViewById(R.id.textViewSize);




        //seekbar



        SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

        seekBar.setProgress(progress);

        textViewFont.setTextSize(textSize+seekBar.getProgress()); // size 30sp

        textViewSize.setText(seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax()); // 0/30


        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            int progressNew = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                textSize = textSize + (progress - progressNew);
                progressNew = progress;
                textViewFont.setTextSize(textSize);
                editor.putInt("progress", progress);
                editor.apply();



            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }


            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                textViewSize.setText(seekBar.getProgress() + "/" + seekBar.getMax()); // 0/30


            }
        });

        //definingmenudrawer

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout4);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view4);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar4);


        //toolbar

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        //toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("");
        //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_dehaze_24);

        //navdrawermenu

        navigationView.bringToFront();
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(fontsize.this, home.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            case R.id.nav_fontsize:
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and here is the string

```
<string name="fontsize">
        <b>بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ</b>
    \n<font size="13">bis-millahir-rahmanir-rahim</font>
    \n\t\t<font size="13">In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful</font>

    </string>
```

please help me and i really appreciate any help and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because you have already set your font size to 13 on the others. Try removing that.